# Braintree Integration "Unable to place order. Please try again later." - Magento 2.1-rc3

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm working the Braintree integration, I have Magento 2.1-rc3 installed.

Two issues are happening:

**1) Error: "Unable to place order. Please try again later." and Magento redirect to Shopping Cart again.**

In this case I checked the debug.log and it shows the status of Submitted to Settlement, it is communicating normally with Braintree, I can find the tests there, but all of them shows "Submitted to settlement" and the order don't go through.

I'm using amounts of $139, $85.90 and the test credit card:

5555 5555 5555 4444

07/17

111

It should go through. Or at least, Magento should show the some more friendly error to the user, maybe to try a different credit card.

**2) Credit Card fields disabled in Google Chrome.**

The payment option shows up, the fields are there, but there is no way to type in, they seems to be disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue with magento 2.1

I've also noticed that the ajax request returns POST 400 Bad Request from the url POST //SITE/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/73e1275fe7e37f8d720f8e516bd9680d/payment-information

debug.log [2016-07-19 03:30:29] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"POST","url":"SITE/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/61f787fc991ff87d979572886b1a37b0/payment-information","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product_173","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []

Using paypal through braintree does checkout successfully.

EDIT:

I was able to track down my issue to a problem with the upgrade script to 2.1.

Running this SQL Fixed my problem

ALTER TABLE sales_invoice_grid ADD base_grand_total decimal(12,4) AFTER grand_total;

See here for old issue:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5409

Comment: Love you man! =P

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for issue #1 could be that you have table prefixing enabled, see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5902

As for issue #2: encountering same issue on a clean installation so created the following bug report: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5903 - no war yet...